# Identity tables in Two MVC 5 applications using same database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a requirement to use one database for two MVC5 applications. So I have one application that creates default Identity tables AspNetUsers etc. Now from another application I want to create separate Identity tables. For that I am trying to rename table names from AspNetUsers to "BackOfficeApplicationUsers". Below are my codes

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("BackOfficeApplicationRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("BackOfficeApplicationUsers");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("BackOfficeApplicationUserClaims");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleId }).ToTable("BackOfficeApplicationUserRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(l => new { l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey, l.UserId }).ToTable("BackOfficeApplicationUserLogins");
}
```

When I do update-database I get an error "AspNetUsers table already exists". I know it's because from my second application it tries to create AspNetUsers table first and then it will rename it. What is the solution to this problem so that both applications have separate Identity tables. Thanks

Comment: ToTable() can take two arguments like this : modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users", "dbo");  can you try with this one and change dbo :)

Comment: @theMost1ted No, this doesn't work. I checked script via update-database -script . It creates table with default schema dbo first and then rename it to     schema "backoffice"

Answer (score 0):

Have each MVC site use a different schema and simplify `OnModelCreating` to set schema based on appSettings:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var schemaName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SchemaName"] ?? "dbo";
    dbModelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(schemaName);
    base.OnModelCreating(dbModelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. I checked script via update-database -script . It creates table with default schema dbo first and then rename it to     schema "backoffice"